# Android Strategic Decision on loading some data (API vs SQLite) - when and how

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have an android app that Im working on that connects to a server via API and gets the following sets of data:

- categories
- subcategories
- countries

that are used in several places in the app, they stay the same throughout the lifecycle of the app and they never change. they will not be modified

I have downloader classes and in the activities that need those sets of data, I have listeners for when the data has been downloaded.

I got to the "Search Items" activity where I have three spinners - categories, subcategories and countries spinner and I started thinking - Im going to have three downloader tasks running here and three different listeners. Is that alright?

Maybe if I run the downloader tasks while the app is loading and put these sets of data in maybe a local SQLite database, is going to be a better decision.
If so, why?

Which of the two practices is more common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that "it depends".  Your question doesn't fully explain what the purpose of your data is, and that's what's going to drive how you consume it.

So clearly it has to come from the server... you mention having multiple listeners.  This is fine, and is often how multiple, asynchronous feeds are consumed.  However, if you're not exactly sure how this is working, it's very easy to cause timing errors or have ineffecient code.  If possible, consider using a framework like [Volley](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io-2013/presentations/110%20-%20Volley-%20Easy,%20Fast%20Networking%20for%20Android.pdf) to manage your web requests, as it's generally easy and efficient.

Once you've got your data, it's then a question of what you want to do with it.  You *definitely* don't want to make the request again, so you're thinking the right way.  But you may not need to store it in a database at all; if the data is session-scoped (that is, the user only needs it for right now, and will want updated data when they use it again) then you're fine just keeping your data objects around in memory, and then get them again from the server when the user restarts your app.

However, if the data doesn't change that often, storing it locally might not be a bad idea, since it will prevent unnecessary data requests.  An sqlite database would be a fine method for that on Android.

The tl;dr is that both of your "options" aren't really competing with each other; take a close look at your goal, and decide when it's appropriate for your app to make data requests (the earlier the better), and if it's appropriate for your app to store data in an sqldatabase.